# Keep an image centered regardless of screen size?

Tags: css

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wkkrnqqx/) I created. I want the decorative ornament to always stay in the middle of the screen. I can't figure out how to do it. I tried wrapping it up in a div but that didn't work either.

HTML

```
<span class="border-top"></span>
```

CSS

```
.border-top {
background: url("http://i.imgur.com/Txoi4sd.png") no-repeat;
clear: both;
display: block;
height: 47px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.border-top {
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/Txoi4sd.png") center center no-repeat;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 47px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<span class="border-top"></span>
```

This will probably do the trick.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background

Comment: Such a simple solution that I overlooked. Thank you. :) I'll mark you in 6 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

what about  http://jsfiddle.net/wkkrnqqx/1/

```
.border-top {
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/Txoi4sd.png") no-repeat;
    display: block;
    height: 47px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-position:50% 0;
}
```